# Jquery.address page jump issue in scrolling scenarios: $.address.wrap()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-address

How to use the "wrap" method of `jquery.address`?

I'm trying to avoid page scrolling jump when i call the `$.address.change(fn)`.
`Jquery.address` add `#` to my url so by default page suddenly scroll to top... ooh this drive me crazy..

> $.address.wrap() Returns: Boolean
>   Provides the state of the wrap mode. Disabled by default.
>
> $.address.wrap(value) Returns: jQuery Address
>   Enables or disables the wrap mode which generates a DIV wrapper around the page content and fixes any scroll issues caused by the use of hash fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `wrap()` before, but avoided scrolling with `return false;` at the end of the `$.address.change(fn)`.