# Ajax Address remain Scroll Position

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery.address

I am using the jquery.address plugin to dynamically load my #content using Ajax. I also am using some effects for loading the new #content (i.e the old #content flies out, the new comes in from top, or from the side etc.) but I think that's not the problem..

Problem is, that after the ajax request, the scroll position does not remain and the page jumps back to the top.

Is there any plugin/soultion on that? I read that storing the current position in a cookie and using $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: x }, t); would help. But isn't there a better maybe more simpler way to accomplish that?

Thanks beforehand!

Mike

**EDIT**

**Solved**: Found out the solution is (comment out .focus()):

```
 // Selects the proper navigation link
 $('#menu a').each(function() {
   //console.log($(this).attr('href'));
     if (($(this).attr('href') == ($.address.state() + event.path)) {
       //$(this).addClass('selected').focus(); // .focus() needs to be commented out in order to prevent to set the focus back to this class
       $(this).addClass('selected');
     }
     else {
       $('#menu ul li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
     }
 });
```

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284596/jquery-address-page-jump-issue-in-scrolling-scenarios-address-wrap but return false; doesn't work for me. Is this to be accomplished with address.wrap()?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with IE, mine does the same thing but works correctly in firefox. AFAIK saving the position and using `scrollTop` like you did, could be the only workarround for IE.